# Remove %f character when plotting time with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, time, graph

I have the following time series in a CSV file:

```
20:01:20,4254215
20:01:36,5216326
20:02:45,6363636
20:02:48,2553266
...
```

The first column is time in format Hour:Minutes:Seconds. The second is another data. I am plotting it the following way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv
from datetime import datetime

...

with open('mydata.dat', 'r') as csvfile:
    myfile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in myfile:
        a = datetime.strptime((row[0]),'%H:%M:%S')
        x.append((a))
        y.append(row[1])

...

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the graph generated has %f in the x Axis. Is there any way to avoid this and only show Hours:Minutes:Seconds?

I attach the current result to show my problem:

[image: Graph generated]

Comment: I don't see commas.

Comment: You are right, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv
from datetime import datetime

x = [];y=[]

with open('data/mydata.dat', 'r') as csvfile:
    myfile = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in myfile:
        a = datetime.strptime((row[0]),'%H:%M:%S')
        x.append((a))
        y.append(row[1])


plt.plot(x, y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

produces this image, without any `"%f"` present in the ticklabels:

[image]

If you see a different image, it might be because you use an old version of matplotlib. You may try to set the DateFormatter explicitely

```
import matplotlib.dates
fmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
```

You may also (or additionally) try to use `plot.plot_date()` instead of `plt.plot()`.

Comment: My bad, the initial data file is converted previously to a CSV file with the "," separator. However I tried with the code you showed and I still get the %f character in the graph generated

Comment: Seems that specifying DateFormatter does the trick. Now the graph shows correctly the time without the %f character. Thanks!